# How to clear all canvas items except entry items?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to delete all the elements of a canvas in tkinter except the entry elements. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Store your other elements in a list upon creation, and loop through it for deletion later.

Comment: What is a canvas "entry" element? There's a tkinter widget named `Entry`, but `Canvas` widgets don't provide a way to create them directly. i.e. there's no `create_entry()` method.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to store a reference of every widget in collections that can be manipulated independently. Here, we separately store `Label`, `Button`, and `Entry`. Upon pressing the `remove all but entry` button, all widgets are destroyed, except the `Entries`

```
import tkinter as tk


def remove_all_but_entries():
    for button in buttons:
        button.destroy()
    for label in labels:
        label.destroy()


root = tk.Tk()

labels = []
labels.append(tk.Label(root, text='make disappear example'))
for label in labels:
    label.pack()

buttons = []
buttons.append(tk.Button(root, text='start', command=lambda: print('button start')))
buttons.append(tk.Button(root, text='stop', command=lambda: print('button stop')))
buttons.append(tk.Button(root, text='remove all but entry', command=remove_all_but_entries))
for button in buttons:
    button.pack()

entries = []
entries.append(tk.Entry(root))
for entry in entries:
    entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Note that the OP wants to clear all _`Canvas`_ "entry elements", not tkinter `Entry` widgets—although I'm not sure what the former are...

Comment: Yes, I noticed @martineau, thank you... From the lack of details in the question, I assumed it was language inaccuracy, but the OP will maybe give us feedback.